# What am I doing wrong in evaluating this triple integral?

Tags: integration, volume

I am required to find the volume common to ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2} = 1$ and cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ay$

I set up the following triple integral:

$$V=2\cdot    \int_{}^{}\int_{R}^{}\int_{z=0}^{\frac{b}{a}\cdot \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2}}dz\cdot dR=   2\frac{b}a \cdot \int_{}^{}\int_{R}^{} \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2} dy dx$$  where R: $x^2+y^2=ay$

Using $x=r\cos(t), y=r\sin(t), dydx = rdrdt$

$$V=2\cdot \frac{b}a \int_{t=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=0}^{asin(t)} \sqrt{a^2 -r^2}\cdot r \;\;  dr dt \; \; \; \; equation -(1)$$

Let $a^2-r^2=m \Rightarrow r\cdot dr=\frac{-1}2dm$

$$V=2\cdot \frac{b}{a}\cdot \frac{-1}2\cdot \int_{t=0}^{\pi}\int_{m=a^2}^{a^2cos^2(t)} \sqrt{m}\;\;  dm dt = \frac23\cdot  \frac{b}{a}\cdot a^3\cdot \int_{t=0}^{\pi}1-\cos^3(t) \; dt $$

Now $\cos^3(\pi-t)=-\cos^3(t) $ Hence its integration is $0$ over $0 $ to $\pi$

$$V=\frac23\cdot ba^2 \cdot(\pi) $$

However the answer given to be is $\frac43 ba^2 (\frac\pi2-\frac23)$

The thing confusing me is if I had used symmetry in equation $(1)$ and multiplied the integral by $2$ in order to reduce the limits of $t$ from $0$ to $\pi/2 $, I am getting the desired result as below :

From equation -$(1)$

$$V=2\cdot \frac{b}a \int_{t=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=0}^{asin(t)} \sqrt{a^2 -r^2}\cdot r \;\;  dr dt  $$

$$= 4\frac{b}a \int_{t=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{asin(t)} \sqrt{a^2 -r^2}\cdot r \;\;  dr dt = 4\frac{b}a \cdot \frac{-1}2\int_{t=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{m=a^2}^{a^2cos^2(t)} \sqrt{m}\; dmdt$$

$$ = 2\frac{b}a \cdot a^3\cdot \frac23 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}1-cos^3(t)\; dt = \frac43\cdot ba^2 (\frac\pi2-\frac23)$$

Where am I going wrong in the first method?

Answer (score 1):

In the first integral the set up should be

$$V=2\cdot    \int_{}^{}\int_{R}^{}\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{b^2 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}y^2}}dz\cdot dR$$

It seems that the problem is in this step for $(a^2\cos^2 t)^\frac32=a^3|\cos t|^3$ and thus

$$V=2\cdot \frac{b}{a}\cdot \frac{-1}2\cdot \int_{t=0}^{\pi}\int_{m=a^2}^{a^2cos^2(t)} \sqrt{m}\;\;  dm dt = \frac23\cdot  \frac{b}{a}\cdot a^3\cdot \int_{t=0}^{\pi}1-\color{red}{|\cos(t)|^3} \; dt$$

Comment: Sorry The denominator of $y^2$ is also $a^2$

Comment: @SoLo Ok I've fixed but I don't understand you first set up. What about mine?

Comment: can you check it again. It should be exactly how I've written in answer now

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2} = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{z^2}{b^2}= 1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2} \Rightarrow z= \pm \frac{b}{a}\cdot \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$